# How to put nested dictionary in csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

Following is a nested dictionary:

```
nested_dict = {
    'Fruit': {
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'B': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        'C': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

    },
    'Vegetable': {
        'A': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        'B': [15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
        'C': [25, 24, 23, 22, 21]
    }
}
```

I want this nested dictionary to be exported in csv and it should look something like this:

[image: desired output]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you've tried.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider utilizing the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module:

```
import csv

nested_dict = {
    'Fruit': {
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'B': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
        'C': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    },
    'Vegetable': {
        'A': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
        'B': [15, 14, 13, 12, 11],
        'C': [25, 24, 23, 22, 21]
    }
}

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
    for category, values in nested_dict.items():
        for i in range(len(values['A'])):
            row = [category] + [values[key][i] for key in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
            writer.writerow(row)
```

**`output.csv`**:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fruit | 1 | 5 | 11 |
| Fruit | 2 | 4 | 12 |
| Fruit | 3 | 3 | 13 |
| Fruit | 4 | 2 | 14 |
| Fruit | 5 | 1 | 15 |
| Vegetable | 11 | 15 | 25 |
| Vegetable | 12 | 14 | 24 |
| Vegetable | 13 | 13 | 23 |
| Vegetable | 14 | 12 | 22 |
| Vegetable | 15 | 11 | 21 |